# Solr not returning documents in id search

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I'm using distributed search with solr 4.2.x and it seems to crash on one of the indexes. The error is a NullPointerException, which I've debugged to the following case

Assuming I have two indexes with documents in them:

- index1 with document of unique document id=idA
- index2 with document of unique document id=idB

When I search the indexes using ids parameter one of them does not return the document - even though it is there (query from admin panel returns it).

Requests I perform:

```
http://solr_server:8983/solr/index1/select?ids=idA
http://solr_server:8983/solr/index2/select?ids=idB
```

and one of them does not return the requested document.

The id part of the schema looks like this (and is the same in both indexes):

```
<fields>

<types>
<fieldType name="textGeneral" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>

</types>

...
<field name="solrDocumentNumber" type="textGeneral" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
...
</fields>

<uniqueKey>solrDocumentNumber</uniqueKey>
```

I use standard requestHandlers.

Comment: in which field, you're storing your id?

Comment: Also, whats the definition for ids field in schema.xml ???

Comment: I'm storing the id in solrDocumentNumber field - since this is defined  as uniqueKey in my schema it is the id of my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Analyzed, Tokenized [TextField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0/org/apache/solr/schema/TextField.html) is not a very good representation of a unique key.  It can lead to unpredictable results.  At very least, you should make a field for your key using [StrField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/StrField.html), or better yet, a [UUIDField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/UUIDField.html).  There are some good recommendations in the Apache wiki on using [Unique Keys in SOLR](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#Unique_key_composition).

Comment: yes, that's right - I've changed the key type and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

search on field where u store the document id number

```
http://solr_server:8983/solr/index1/select?q=solrDocumentNumber:idA
```